# Creating a DataTemplate in Code: Can I use the Template property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I'm attempting to use a `DataTemplateSelector` with a particular third-party WPF grid control, and I'm having trouble determining if the issues I'm having are a bug in the control or my own lack of understanding about the conventions of WPF data templates.

I realize that the ordinary use case of a `DataTemplate` is to declare it somewhere in XAML (be it as a resource or explicitly where it's used), but my particular project would benefit greatly if I could create the template in code (C#, specifically) rather than in XAML. The issue I'm running into is the fact that my code-created `DataTemplate` uses a `FrameworkElementFactory` as the template's `VisualTree`, whereas a XAML-created template uses a `TemplateContent` object as the template's `Template` value. As best I can tell right now, the grid control in question works with templates that use `Template`, but doesn't seem to play nicely with templates that use `VisualTree`.

By way of comparison, here's what one of the templates looks like in XAML as part of my selector:

```
<MySelectorType>
    <MySelectorType.BooleanTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <EditorControl Name="Reserved_Name" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </MySelectorType.BooleanTemplate>
</MySelectorType>
```

And here's how I'm trying to create an equivalent template in code:

```
var template = new DataTemplate()
{
    VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(EditorControl)) 
                 { 
                     Name = "Reserved_Name" 
                 }
};
```

I've also tried it like this:

```
var template = new DataTemplate()
{
    VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(EditorControl))
};

template.VisualTree.SetValue(EditorControl.NameProperty, "Reserved_Name");
```

Which seemed more analogous to what the XAML template would do, but that appeared not to work *at all* (the editor neither read or set the value, where at least the first version would read it).

Is it possible for my in-code template to use the `Template` property rather than `VisualTree`? According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatecontent.aspx), there's no public API for this type and the instantiation path is complex, but has this been done? The only [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/d897806e-36ce-464e-9bbe-4640a2a5a006) I've found uses hardcoded XAML in the code, which doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is the template not being created? Is the name not being found by a binding?

Comment: @CodeNaked: As to what *specifically* isn't working, I can't say; I have been in touch with the grid's developer and they say they've found the problem and are working on a solution, but I'd prefer not to have to wait on them if possible.

Comment: I mean, what are you seeing :-) Do you see the EditorControl in the grid, but it doesn't work? or is the EditorControl just not showing up?

Comment: @Code: Sorry ;) The control shows up no matter which way I choose, but using the code-based template code above the value is only *read* from the underlying object; attempting to manipulate the editor has no effect. If I return the value of the property that's being initialized in XAML instead, the editor behaves normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not like this way of doing things either but this actually is the recommended way, in the documentation of the [`FrameworkElementFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx) the following can be found:

> This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates, which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when you create a template using this class. The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class.

I do not know of any simple way to use the `Template` property in code, the only way to my knowledge that might be possible is via *a lot* of reflection.

---

Setting names is a special case, if you set the `Name` property of the factory it should be properly registered, if not you need to get the approriate [`Namescope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope.aspx) and [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope.registername.aspx) the name manually.

Comment: How do you register an object's name with a DataTemplate though, since the object isn't created yet? :-)

Comment: @CodeNaked: Indeed, that would require using some `Loaded` event or the like. Using the `FrameworkElementFactory.Name` seemed to work for me so far though.

Comment: Yuck. I was really hoping there was some sort of secret but functional API somewhere that would let me do this in a type-safe way.